# CK Finder Amazon S3 connector Upload Strategy

Tags: amazon-s3, ckfinder

We are planning to use CKFinder 3 as a upload manager in our Single Page Application while uploading Files to Amazon S3, I believe CKFinder 3 has an inbuilt connector for Amazon S3 but I wanted to know what strategy this connector internally uses, does it directly upload from client side (Html/Javascript) to S3 or does it internally goes to Server and then upload to S3 from Server

Answer (score 0):

The upload of files works the same regardless of the [resource type](http://docs.cksource.com/ckfinder3-php/configuration.html#configuration_options_resourceTypes) and [backend](http://docs.cksource.com/ckfinder3-php/configuration.html#configuration_options_backends). So from client side the interface is one a server connector.

After uploading a file to the server connector, the connector saves the file using an apropriate method for a given resource type. So in case of Amazon S3 the file is being uploaded to Amazon by the webserver.